# Query com OPERADOR IN retornar apenas os registros que possuem todos os valores informados

Tags: sql

Estou com uma dúvida de como retornar registros de uma tabela de possuem todos os valores informados no operador `IN` utilizando `JOIN` em outra tabela.

Tenho uma tabela de bandeiras, cores e outra fazendo a relação entre as duas(bandeiras e cores);

> tabela bandeira -> bandeira_id, nomeBandeira
>
> tabela cor -> cor_id, nomeCor
>
> tabela bandeira_cor -> id, bandeira_id, cor_id

Supondo que a cor 1 seja Azul e a cor 2 seja Branco como faço para pegar bandeiras que tenham as cores Azul e Branco e não somente o Branco ou somente com Azul.

Tentei utilizar o operador `IN` mas trouxe as bandeiras que possuem a cor Azul ou Branca.

```
SELECT nomeBandeira FROM bandeira INNER JOIN cor  WHERE cor.cor_id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Qual o SGBD que estás a utilizar?

Comment: Acho que independe de SGBD...

Comment: Se ele estiver a usar o SQL Server posso resolver usando window functions. Se estiver a usar MySql não poderei fazer isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso que você quer fazer se chama [*divisão relacional*](http://www.itnerante.com.br/profiles/blogs/divis-o-relacional-part-i). Existem várias formas de implementar isso em SQL; a que eu usei [nesse SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b86ef/4) é, eu acho, a mais simples, cortesia do [Joe Celko](https://www.simple-talk.com/author/joe-celko/):

```
SELECT
  bandeira_nome,
  COUNT(cor_id) AS total_cores
FROM
  bandeira
  INNER JOIN bandeira_cor USING (bandeira_id)
  INNER JOIN cor USING (cor_id)
WHERE cor_nome in ("Azul", "Branco")
GROUP BY bandeira_nome
HAVING total_cores = 2
```

Comment: ctgPi, era isso que eu queria! =) Obrigado!